# "Given" versus "Given that"

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

I just received a proofread version of an academic manuscript from my copy editor. She essentially changed all of the instances in which I had written ***"given that"*** to ***"given."*** I've tried to read up on the distinction, but I am getting contradictory information. From a reading-aloud perspective, it just does not sound right to me to take out the "that", but that may just be my bias.

For example:

> "Given that the CEO had recently resigned, the company had trouble raising its next round of financing."

was changed to

> "Given the CEO had recently resigned, the company had trouble raising its next round of financing."

Are "given" and "given that" actually interchangeable? According to the dictionary, they both mean "when you consider something"...

Comment: It might help if you include a couple of examples of the text that was changed so that we can see the context.

Comment: @KillingTime, great suggestion. I have added the one that perplexes me the most. Does that help?

Comment: Since the expression "(that) the CEO had recently resigned" is a declarative content clause, the subordinator "that" is indeed omissible. Personally, I think it sounds better with "that". Others may disagree.

Comment: SHJ9000 – I agree with you and BillJ – it sounds much better with *that*. Also, I really don't get why people hand out down votes for posts that clearly don't deserve them – especially when the person who wrote the post is new to the site... I think your question is valid and interesting, so I've upvoted it for you – like I said: it certainly doesn't deserve a down vote anyway.

Comment: The use of *that* is optional. I prefer its presence. But, whether it's preferred or not, it's inclusion certainly isn't a mistake that needs to be corrected. Not unless some very specific version of stylistic editing is taking place. But, if that's the case, the editor should be ready to defend their personal opinion on the matter, backing it up with some kind of objective evidence that the use of *that* has a negative impact on the manuscript's target audience in some way. Otherwise, it's the editor inappropriately imposing their own stylistic voice in place of yours.

Comment: No chance Jason Bassford: Don't you know that editors are demigods, not to be argued with?!

Comment: Given (that) both the original and the changes are grammatical, why bother arguing with your copy-editor?

Comment: @BillJ I do indeed agree. However, just to be a pain in the posterior,  I *don't* agree that because *(that) the CEO had recently resigned* is a declarative content clause, the subordinator *that* is omissible. Why? Well the word *given* here is a preposition according to the kind of grammar that we both subscribe to. Most prepositions that take content clauses do *not* allow expanded content clauses (i.e. ones with the word *that*). Consider * *After that the party finished, I went for a veggie kebab*, for example. So *given* is a member of an important set of exceptional prepositions here.

Comment: @PeterShor Well, maybe because, as most of the contributors here agree, the OP feels that it's better *with* the word "that"? Maybe also to prevent a tide of trivial edits in the future?

Comment: @Hannah Indeed, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Araucaria I know that "given" permits expandable content clauses. But that's not why "that" is optional. It's optional because it very often  is with declarative content clauses. If, hypothetically, it were the other way round, with a prep like, say, "before", that cannot take an expandable content clause, then non-expandability would indeed be a reason for "that" being deleted by the editor.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I'm with you, but it's this case that's the exception amongst preps though! ;-) [See my post below]

Comment: @SHJ9000 Why don't you just ask your editor why she deleted "that" in your manuscript.

Comment: @BillJ She deleted it because it was grammatically unnecessary and, in her view, writing should be parsimonious.

Comment: @PeterShor, Araucaria is right. To me, this seemed like a stylistic choice, and I do not think that it is the copy editor's job to alter the writer's style except to correct grammar and resolve linguistic ambiguity. However, I wanted to validate through your collective wisdom whether this was in fact just style.

Comment: @SHJ9000 I think you have your answer, so we can consider your question dealt with unanimously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) give a list of adverbs and prepositions that take content clauses as complements (p. 971). The majority of these items do not allow *that* at the beginning of the content clause - they take **non-expandable** clauses:

- Though [that the complainants are wealthy], .... (ungrammatical)
- Though [the complainants are wealthy], ....

However, they also list an important subset of prepositions and adverbs which can take **expandable** content clauses. In the case of these items, the word *that* is permissible and may often be preferred, but is also optional. Here is an example with the item *provided*:

- I'll come along, [provided (that) I can leave early]. (p. 971 example (56.ii.a))

The item *given (that)* is also included in this list. This shows that the Original Poster's [OP's] original examples were perfectly correct and entirely grammatical.

There are three possibilities with regard to the editor's interference here. Firstly, they may be unaware that *given* can take expanded clauses with *that* - possible, but maybe unlikely. A second is that they feel that it's better style in many of the OP's cases not to use *that*. A third possibility is that they are just trying to save space, ink and money.

I agree with the OP that their particular examples sound better with *that* included. But that's taste for you; it rarely has much to do with grammaticality. It seems to me that the editor has some explaining to do here.

---

<sup>The *Cambridge Grammar* analyses many items that traditional grammars take to be subordinating conjunctions as prepositions. Nothing at all hinges on this.</sup>

Comment: Would that grammar were so simple. "Though that the complainants are wealthy is undeniable, they are nonetheless unable to buy justice."

Comment: @TimLymington Nice example! But I have good news; in this case the grammar *is* still that simple :) There is indeed an expanded content clause in your example, but it is not the complement of *though*. Rather, it is the subject of the larger clause "[*that[ the complainanats are wealthy]] is undeniable*". (A declarative clause being a subject is actually one of the situations where we *must* use an expanded clause - an unexpanded clause would be ungrammatical). It is this larger clause which is the complement of the word *though*. And *this* clause is non-expandable. Consider: ...

Comment: @TimLymington * "*Though that that the complainants are wealthy is undeniable, they are unable to buy justice*".

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks very much for the clear and concise answer!

Comment: @SHJ9000 We aim to please. Please continue to post good questions (or answer them!).

Comment: @TimLymington I’ve put the comma in after the though-adjunct. Does that make it clearer in the post?

Answer (score 0):

Though this may not satisy your 'teacher', **given that** is appropriate:

**given that**  a phrase  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/given-that-something)

> If you say **given that** X is the case, you mean taking that fact
>   into account.

As in your usage:

*"Given that the CEO had recently resigned, the company had trouble raising its next round of financing."*

and

> Usually, I am sensible with money, as I have to be, given that I don't
>   earn that much.

Answer (score 0):

"Given the recent resignation of the CEO, the company had trouble raising its next round of financing."

or

"Given that the CEO had recently resigned, the company had trouble raising its next round of financing."

Comment: This is not an answer. It merely repeats elements of the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/419214)